# AWS create an alias for my EC2 instance IP

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip, ip-address

I'm not expert in anything related with networks. I've reasearched through Internet but I'm not able to get with the solution for what I need.

It's simple. I've bought a domain in ***GoDaddy.com*** and I've redirected it succesfully to my AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu instance), as you can see:

http://danigarcia-dev.com

But, as you can see, the resulting addres is:

***http://ec2-52-26-205-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/***

But, I would like my domain and the EC2 instance web addresses to be the same:
 ***danigarcia-dev.com***

Is that possible somehow? How can I get an alias for it in AWS?

Comment: How have you redirected the domain?

Comment: @CraigWatson As I've said, I'm quite lost in network's matters. I've tried modifying the /etc/hosts file with "127.0.0.1 localhost danigarcia-dev" and it's not working. I've done a few tries like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have set your domain up for *web forwarding* rather than *DNS redirection*. To get redirection without URL rewriting, you'll need to point your *domain apex* to your EC2 instance using a CNAME record.

So, using the [GoDaddy documentation](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names?countrysite=uk), create a CNAME record with `@` as the **Host**, and `ec2-52-26-205-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` as the **Points to**.

Comment: Done that, error occurs when I save the CNAME record "The specified record already exists.
CNAME - @". I've deleted all the defaults records, maybe I have to wait first..?

Comment: It finally worked, but instead of create a CNAME record with `@` as the **Host**, I've done it with `www`

Comment: I would like to do it with `@`, but it seem is not possible, any solution for this?

Comment: You don't need an alias.  You know the IP address, so you can just create it as an `A` record in the DNS configurator for `@`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, based on @CraigWatson answer, the next configuration on *GoDaddy* ***DNS Zone File*** of the **`danigarcia-dev.com`** domain:

- Create a CNAME record with:

  - `www` as the ***Host***
  - `ec2-52-26-205-227.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` as the ***Points to***
- A forwarding to the **`www.danigarcia-dev.com`** web address